# Heroku | Node.js: No cedar-supported app detected

Tags: node.js, heroku

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to push this simple app to Heroku:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.get ("/", function(req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World')
});

app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

from the git root directory containing these files:

```
drwxr-xr-x@  9 test  staff   306 27 Okt 20:41 .
drwx------@ 16 test  staff   544 27 Okt 20:28 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 test  staff  6148 22 Okt 08:57 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 test  staff   374 27 Okt 20:28 .git
-rw-r--r--@  1 test  staff    18 27 Okt 16:05 Procfile
-rw-r--r--@  1 test  staff   196 27 Okt 15:46 index.js
drwxr-xr-x@  3 test  staff   102 27 Okt 20:28 node_modules
-rw-r--r--@  1 test  staff   323 27 Okt 20:41 package.json
-rw-r--r--@  1 test  staff   323 27 Okt 20:31 package.json~
```

where the package.json has this content:

```
{
  "name": "podio_script",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
   "express": "4.13.3"
  },
  "engines": {
   "node": "0.12.7"
  },
  "author": "James Dean",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

and the Procfile has this content:

```
web: node index.js
```

**What my problem is**

When I run `git push heroku master` I get this error message:

> !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected remote: HINT:
>   This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack remote:       to
>   use for this application automatically. remote: See
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

The ressources I have been able to find tell me that this message is caused by a missing package.json file. But in my case the file is there.

What am I doing wrong? TIA

Comment: hey just tried this and i don't see any issues, i created a default express app, placed your index.js(instead of app.js) and replaced package.json with yours , pushed to heroku and voilla , no errors https://morning-chamber-5036.herokuapp.com/   only thing is, i don't have Procfile ... vl try with that later

Comment: It also works for me -- are you sure your package.json file is included in Git? EG: Make sure it is actually committed AND pushed to Heroku, otherwise you'll get the above error.

Comment: thank you, aishwatsingh and rdegges. It was indeed a fundamental beginner-error: the files where not committed. It is working now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following git steps have to be performed before pushing to Heroku:

```
git init // create repository
git add [files] // add all relevant files to the repository
git commit // commit the new files
```